# Как правильно задать ограничение на количество строк в файле?

Tags: c#, файлы, limit

Есть список

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

Через каждые 5 минут я заношу туда данные.

Через полчаса я записываю данные в файл и хочу чтобы в файле было ограничение на количество строк. Допустим чтобы не было больше 1000 строк в файле.

**Вопрос**

Как логически правильно продумать логику без создания буферных таблиц, подсчета текущего количества и т.д. Как нибудь переопределить метод StreamWriter? Подскажите элегантное решение.

Comment: почему бы просто не считать сколько строк уже записано?

Comment: а что вы будете делать с лишними, если в списке 1200 строк например; выкидывать, записывать с следующий файл?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
List<string> save = new List<string>();
int count = 3;

lst.Add("111");
lst.Add("222");
lst.Add("333");
lst.Add("444");
lst.Add("555");

save = lst.GetRange(0, count);
lst.RemoveRange(0, count);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.